# VS Code documentation on completion not shown

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

The documentation on completion is not shown in VS Code even if the language server sends the `completionItem/resolve` with documentation.

[image: screenshot of vscode]

```
[Trace - 3:33:37 PM] Sending request 'completionItem/resolve - (33)'.
Params: {
    "label": "append",
    "detail": "'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list",
    "insertTextFormat": 1,
    "textEdit": {
        "newText": "append",
        "range": {
            "start": {
                "line": 10,
                "character": 5
            },
            "end": {
                "line": 10,
                "character": 5
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": 12,
    "sortText": "0003",
    "data": {
        "textDocument": {
            "uri": "file:///Users/ulugbekna/codef/scratch-ocaml/gadt.mli"
        },
        "position": {
            "line": 10,
            "character": 5
        }
    },
    "deprecated": false
}


[Trace - 3:33:37 PM] Received response 'completionItem/resolve - (33)' in 3ms.
Result: {
    "label": "append",
    "kind": 12,
    "detail": "'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list",
    "documentation": {
        "kind": "markdown",
        "value": "Concatenate two lists. Same as the infix operator `@`.\nNot tail-recursive \\(length of the first argument\\)."
    },
    "deprecated": false,
    "sortText": "0003",
    "insertTextFormat": 1,
    "textEdit": {
        "range": {
            "start": {
                "line": 10,
                "character": 5
            },
            "end": {
                "line": 10,
                "character": 5
            }
        },
        "newText": "append"
    }
}
```

The screenshot is from an OCaml file. I'm using `OCaml Platform` extension and `ocamllsp` language server.

Comment: what if you type Ctrl+Space

Comment: What rioV8 said, you need to switch to the "detailed view". Instead of pressing the shortcut you can also click the "Read More" button that appears on the right when you hover over it. https://i.imgur.com/hnvt4Nt.png

Comment: @rioV8 on my another computer the documentation is shown without ctrl+space; ctrl+space doesn't help